# Matrix Representation of Strided and Dilated Convolutions

Tags: linear-algebra, convolution

I'm exploring the matrix representation of strided and dilated convolutions, having understood standard 1D convolutions as Toeplitz matrix-vector multiplications. My queries are:

1. **Strided Convolution**: How is strided convolution, which downsamples the input, represented in matrix form? Furthermore, how does this downsampling affect the composition of multiple-strided convolutions in matrix multiplication?
2. **Dilated Convolution**: How can dilated convolution be represented in a matrix framework?

Insights or mathematical references on these topics would be greatly appreciated.